# Calling a promise recursively

Tags: javascript, promise, react.js

I'm trying to call a promise recursively. If I get a `responseData` with a key error I want to call the promise again and again until I don't get it.

```
  _getUser (url) {
    console.log('fetching url', url)
    return fetch(`$(url)/api`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {},
      body: '{"key" : "body"}'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log('Getting responseData', responseData)
      if (responseData[0].error) {
        alert(responseData[0].error.description)
        return _getUser(url)
      } else alert('User Created')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Is this the best way to call a promise recursively to do what I want?

Comment: It won't work at all unless you `return _getUser(url);`.

Comment: Yep sorry I forgot that. Anything else?

Comment: You're never checking `response`'s status code and stuff, so if there's an actual error that doesn't return JSON there won't be a retry. And the caller of your function cannot even distinguish the two cases, since you're `catch`ing all errors an return `undefined` just as in the success case. The general approach at recursion is fine however.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can improve:

Retry in all error cases by doing the recursive call in the `catch` function. 
And limit the number of retries

```
_getUser (url, triesRemaining) {
    console.log('fetching url', url)
    return fetch(`$(url)/api`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {},
      body: '{"key" : "body"}'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log('Getting responseData', responseData)
      if (responseData[0].error) {
        alert(responseData[0].error.description)
        throw new Error();
      } else alert('User Created')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      if(triesRemaining>0) {
        return _getUser(url,triesRemaining-1)
      } else {
        throw new Error('Could not create user. Max amount of tries reached');
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Pieter's suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142921/106289), you could generalize this pattern into a `withRetries` function:

```
withRetries (n, body) {
  // Attempts to execute body.
  // If an exception is thrown, body will be retried up to n times.
  // If the nth time fails, the exception is propagated.
  return body()
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    if (n > 0) {
      return withRetries(n - 1, body)
    } else {
      throw new Error('Maximum number of retries exceeded');
    }
  })
}
```

Now we can write `_getUser` as:

```
_getUser (url) {
  console.log('fetching url', url)
  return withRetries(MAX_RETRIES, function() {
    return fetch(`$(url)/api`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {},
      body: '{"key" : "body"}'
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log('Getting responseData', responseData)
      if (responseData[0].error) {
        alert(responseData[0].error.description)
        throw new Error(); // Fail and retry
      } else alert('User Created')
    })
  })
}
```

You could further factor out the JSON parsing / error handling code into its own function as well.